# Replace occurrences of a list of strings in a string without a cursor in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Boy, that's a mouthful...

I want to parse tokens out of a string. The tokens can be a word or a phrase and what I want is to replace each occurrence of any of the tokens with a string. I'd like to do this without using a cursor.

Ex.

```
declare @str varchar(256) = 'I want this type to be left and of type to be gone. the and a should also be gone of course remains'

create table #Tokens (token varchar(50))
go

insert table (token) values ('of type')
insert table (token) values ('a')
insert table (token) values ('the')
insert table (token) values ('to')
insert table (token) values ('of')
go
```

what I want is an inline function that will replace any of the list of tokens found in the string with '' (empty string).

Comment: I think everyone will say to you about what have you done? Strongly suggest you to modify your question or you are going to start receiving downvotes

Comment: I want to know how to do this. So far, I have no ideas and am guessing you do not either.

Comment: Actually I have, a function who loops the table of tokens and makes a replace in every loop of your string, maybe there is something more elegant but that's the logic

Comment: I always wonder how come, that in most cases persons who ask some shaky questions are telling people they do not know that they do not know the answer, just because they dare to mention the problems of the question.

Comment: I clarified the question. I guess it wasn't clear that I wanted SQL only.

Comment: This is easy to do, but hard (nigh-impossible) to do *efficiently* with anything less than SQLCLR.

Comment: I'd be curious what requirements resulted in you coming to the need for this as a solution...SQL isn't the best with string functions when it comes down to it, not sure if there is a pure sql solution for this.  Reconsidering why you want this as a solution might be a first step.  There are some 'gotcha' type issues here as well...if you remove the token 'of' before 'of type', you will end up leaving the 'type' behind.  Removing the token 'a' will get rid of all 'a' in any word, and i doubt that is your intent.

Comment: I got this sqlfiddle for you with a cursor (why you dont want it as a cursor? ) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0fd2/2

Comment: Cursors are handy but they perform very poorly on large datasets.  The set-based approach in my answer does not suffer from this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A very simple answer would be to use the following:

```
USE tempdb;

DECLARE @str VARCHAR(256);

SET @str = 'I want this type to be left and of type to be gone.
           the and a should also be gone of course remains';

CREATE TABLE #Tokens (token VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #Tokens (token) VALUES ('of type');
INSERT INTO #Tokens (token) VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO #Tokens (token) VALUES ('the');
INSERT INTO #Tokens (token) VALUES ('to');
INSERT INTO #Tokens (token) VALUES ('of');

SELECT @str = REPLACE(@str, token, '')
FROM #Tokens;

SELECT @str;

DROP TABLE #Tokens;
```

Which returns:

```
I wnt this type  be left nd   be gone.  nd  should lso be gone  course remins
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this with a REAL table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[funStripSpecialCharacters]
(
   @inputString as varchar(max)
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    select @inputString = REPLACE(@inputString, SpecialCharacter, '') 
      from SpecialCharacters
    RETURN @inputString
END
```