# Need to parse a column, pull reference values, and perform mathematical operations using TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, parsing, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to create an income statement from tables used by our ancient ERP system. I have one table, which contains amounts and formulas. I need to take these formulas and calculate amounts, but I'm not sure of the best way to do that:

```
RowID | Description                 | Amount
470   | Gross Furniture Revenue     | 324654    
471   | Less:Medals & Specials      | -12345
472   | Adjusted Gross Furn.Revenue | r0470+r0471
```

The formulas won't always be additive. Some are "r2210/2" or "r670-r700-r710". How can I calculate these using tsql so that I have one clean table of values to pass through to my report?

Comment: That's...a very weird way to have data stored, it looks like you'll need to do a dynamic query.

Comment: I know, it's horrible. Any ideas on how I would do that?

Comment: what does r0470 mean? would you discard the r?

Comment: You would need to discard the r and the 0...pretty much something that removes the character and turns it into a full int, it would be pretty complicated to do this in SQL since you would need to have a string split that splits all math symbols.

Comment: You're basically talking about writing a parser in SQL that will parse this possibly poorly-defined language into SQL.  SQL is not really a great language to try to write a parser in...

Comment: @april4181 please clarify the meaning of those r numbers. Are your sure those are math expressions?

Comment: The r's are just a reference to that row. R470 is row 470, so those can be disgarded. This would need to run daily as part of a stored procedure, which is why I was looking to write it in SQL. I suppose I could call a SSIS package that has a script in some other language for this?

Comment: Just pondering something ridiculous like generating a pile of dynamic SQL that: finds the non-formula lines and loads the values into variables, e.g. `declare @R0470 as Decimal(10,2) = 324654;`, then appends variables to handle the calculations, e.g. `declare @R0472 as Decimal(10,2) = @R0470 + @R0471;`, then stores the results in a suitable table. Note that generating the dependency tree for the formulae may not be trivial, i.e. if row 42 is `r0472 / r0011` then you need to calculate row 472 before row 42.

Comment: @april4181  Please review the answers provided.  If at least one of the answers solves your issue, please award the green tick to the best answer so that future SO readers don't have to read the whole page to discover the best solution.  If neither answer is satisfactory, please give feedback on each answer so that other users may attempt to deliver a new solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid writing the parser in SQL, even if it is possible there are much better languages for such stuff. I would:

scan the table
   - amounts is stored in a dictionary
   - for each formula, tokenize the formula and put it on a stack. In your example

```
   lookup(0470)
   lookup(0471)
   op "+"
```

evaluate the expressions until the stack contains one element (result of the formula) and put that in the lookup table, etc.

Answer (score 0):

-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881913/replace-occurrences-of-a-list-of-strings-in-a-string-without-a-cursor-in-t-sql

-- Code takes your original string pointer report definition, then replacing the reference pointers with the formulas, generate a line execution plan

```
-- ORIGINAL REPORT FORMULATIONS
DECLARE @REPORT AS TABLE (RowID BIGINT,[Description] VARCHAR(MAX),Amount VARCHAR(MAX));

-- RABLE FROM THE OUTPUTED FINAL REPORT
DECLARE @FinalReport AS TABLE (RowID BIGINT,[Description] VARCHAR(MAX),Amount VARCHAR(MAX));

-- TABLE TO STORE CONVERSTION CROSS REVERANCE IN
DECLARE @DO TABLE (REF VARCHAR(MAX),[ACTION] VARCHAR(MAX));     

DECLARE 
@RID BIGINT,                                                --- REPORT POINTER TO READ FROM CURSOR
@DESC VARCHAR(MAX),                                         --- REPORT DESCRIPTION TO READ FROM CURSOR
@FORMULA VARCHAR(MAX),                                      --- FORMULA FOR REPORT DEFINITION
@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),                                         --- SQL TO PASS TO  SP_EXECUTESQL
@PRAMS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '@RETURN AS DECIMAL(18,10) OUTPUT',  --- PRAMAS USED IN SP_EXECUTESQL
@RETURNED DECIMAL(18,10)                                    --- VALUE RETURNED FROM SP_EXECUTESQL

-- LOAD UP REPORT EXAMPLES      
INSERT INTO @REPORT (RowID,[Description],Amount) VALUES
(470,'Gross Furniture Revenue','10000'),
(471,'Less:Medals & Specials','-7500'),
(472,'Adjusted Gross Furn.Revenue','R0470+R0471'),
(473,'1/2 X SUBTOTAL','R0472/2'),
(474,'ADD SOME VALUE','283.45'),
(475,'TOTAL','R0473+R0474');

-- CREATE CROSS REF TABLE DATA
INSERT INTO @DO (REF,[ACTION])
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM('R' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(RowID AS VARCHAR(10)),4))) AS REF ,RTRIM(LTRIM(Amount)) AS [ACTION] FROM @REPORT;

-- LOOP THROUGH REPORT DEFINITION FILE TO GENERATE FINAL REPORT
DECLARE BUILDREPORT CURSOR FOR SELECT RowID,[Description],Amount FROM @REPORT;

OPEN BUILDREPORT;

FETCH NEXT FROM BUILDREPORT INTO @RID, @DESC, @FORMULA;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

-- NOTE, BESURE TO WRAP THE SUBSTITUTED FORMULAS IN BRACKETS TO INSURE CORRECT CALCULATIONS
    SELECT @FORMULA = REPLACE(@FORMULA, REF, '(' + [ACTION] + ')') FROM @DO ORDER BY REF DESC;

-- REPLACE REF WITH VALUES
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT @RETURN = CAST((' + @FORMULA + N') AS DECIMAL(18,10)) '

-- PROCESS CALCULATIONS
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL , @PRAMS, @RETURN = @RETURNED OUTPUT

-- OUTPUT REPORT
    INSERT INTO @FinalReport(RowID,[Description],Amount) VALUES(@RID, @DESC,@RETURNED);

    FETCH NEXT FROM BUILDREPORT INTO @RID, @DESC, @FORMULA;
END;

CLOSE BUILDREPORT;

DEALLOCATE BUILDREPORT;

-- SHOW REPORT
SELECT * FROM @FinalReport
```

Comment: please edit your answer to include your comment text at the top of your answer then delete your comment, this will benefit future SO readers by putting all necessary information in its proper, expected place.