# I need to replace keywords with they match a token - sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

1. I have a table that has a string(sig) that may or may not have keywords I need to replace.  Words in string(sig) are separated by a space.
2. I have a table that holds tokens(token_column) and what they represent(token_expansion).
3. If a keyword in the string(sig) matches with a token(token_column), replace the keyword with the expansion(token_expansion)

I'm not sure where to start with this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is being run in sql.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Some of them allow to split a string and make an (in-memory) table out of it, then the task becomes trivial. Some need much more ceremony.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace occurrences of a list of strings in a string without a cursor in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881913/replace-occurrences-of-a-list-of-strings-in-a-string-without-a-cursor-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dumped token and expansion into a table called sigtoken.

columns(id, language, token, text)

(1, 'E', '*OD', 'Right Eye')

I then went through each line and each keyword to see if it matches and then updated it.  I created a function for this then called it wherever I needed.